# sort rows in excel programmatically

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am fairly new in generating excel reports using vb.net. My problem is I can't seem to properly sort the rows.[image: Check my excel here]

What I want to do is sort all the rows including the client name using the total value as the reference. I use interop assembly and this is the code that I've tried but it does not even work properly.

```
Dim myRange As Excel.Range

    myRange = Wsheet.Range("A7:AG17")
    myRange.Select()
    myRange.Sort(Key1:=myRange.Range("AG7:AG17"), _
                            Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, _
                            Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows, _
                            SortMethod:=Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, _
                            DataOption1:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to achieve what you want first?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use your ranges, but to sort your data by the totals have you tried recording a macro whilst doing it manually first?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AG8:AG16" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A7:AG16")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: I actually did. I tried to apply the code generated by the macro but I am having error on the `.apply` part or is it because I am using the interop assembly?